# Highcharts variable threshold

Tags: variables, highcharts, threshold, adaptive-threshold

Is it possible to set a threshold that changes across the series?
like the picture attached?[image: Dynamic threshold]

I already went through this link ( http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts )and couldn't find anything similar, only static thresholds.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to mix line serie and areasplinerange, then set proper colors. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2zyzx1fr/1/

Comment: Great idea, hadn't thought about it. It works just fine for what I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: I added that comment as post, so please check that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to mix line serie and `areasplinerange`, then set proper colors.

```
series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        data: [3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
    }, {
        fillColor: 'green',
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        },
        data: [
            [3, 3],
            [2, 5],
            [3, 3]
        ]
    }, {
        fillColor: 'red',
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        },
        data: [null, null, [3, 3],
            [3, 5],
            [3, 4],
            [5, 10],
            [4, 12]
        ]
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2zyzx1fr/1